# jupyter python code executed but proper output is not displayed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, facebook-prophet

I ran a piece of code in Jupyter (python) and it executed perfectly, however the output piece is displayed as it is stored in some location (image below). Any advice on how to actually get the output instead?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to see?  There shouldn't be any output at this point.

Comment: I was following an tutorial at [link] (https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-with-prophet-in-python/) where they generated an output regarding model performance, which in my case isn't visible